# Binary tree maze generation in Elixir

Tags: ruby, functional-programming, elixir, immutability

I have an implementation of a binary tree maze generation in Ruby, in a purely OO way. I'm trying to rewrite this in Elixir as a learning exercise but I'm running into some problems with OO vs FP paradigms.

I render a grid containing cells. When walking through the grid using the binary tree algorithm, for every cell I decide to link up with either the northern or the eastern cell next to it. This linking, in the Ruby implementation is bidirectional:

```
def link(cell, bidirectional=true)
  @links[cell] = true
  cell.link(self, false) if bidirectional
  self
end

def unlink(cell, bidirectional=true)
  @links.delete cell
  cell.unlink(self, false) if bidirectional
  self
end
```

So it links the cell to the neighbour, and the neighbour to the cell. I cannot figure out how to do this in Elixir. I have the first part of the function down:

```
def link(cell, neighbour, bidirectional) do
  %{ cell | links: cell.links ++ [neighbour]}
end



test "it links cells in a bidirectional way" do
  cell = Cell.create(1, 1)
  neighbour = Cell.create(2, 2)

  %{ row: _, column: _, links: cell_links } = Cell.link(cell, neighbour, true)
  assert Enum.member? cell_links, neighbour
  # ?? check if neighbour links includes cell, but cannot get a reference to "new" neighbour
end
```

but then the bidirectional call is giving me troubles. I can do the call without a problem but since I'm dealing with immutable data, I'll never be able to get a reference to the "new" neighbouring cell with the correct links array.

Implementing a GenServer for every cell seems a bit like an anti-pattern to me. There surely must be a way to implement this behaviour in a purely functional way; I'm new to FP however and would love some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On pattern you can use when mapping OO to sequential Elixir (functional language in general), you can create a data object (not an OO object) and pass it around as the first argument to your functions. This way, you are transforming that data on each call.

So, your api would be shaped like `def link(maze, cell, bidirectional \\ true)`. Using a map to represent the maze with an `{x,y}` tuple as the key and a map as the value lets you access individual cells and update them.

Here is some untested code as an example.

```
def Maze do
  def new, do: %{cells: %{], links: %{}, start: {0,0}}}

  def link(maze, cell1, cell2, bidirectional \\ true) do
    maze
    |> put_in([:links, cell2], true)
    |> link_bidirectional(cell1, bidirectional)
  end

  defp link_bidirectional(maze, _, _, false), do: maze
  defp link_bidirectional(maze, cell1, cell2, _) do
    link(maze, cell2, cell1, false)
  end
end
```

EDIT: Here is a functional solution for linking

```
defmodule Maze do
  def new do 
    %{cells: %{{0, 0} => Cell.create(0,0)}, tree: {{0, 0}, nil, nil}}
  end

  def new_cell(maze, row, column) do
    # ignoring the tree for now
    put_in(maze, [:cells, {row, column}], Cell.create(row, column))
  end

  def link(maze, cell1, cell2, bidirectional \\ true)
  def link(maze, %{} = cell1, %{} = cell2, bidirectional) do
    maze
    |> update_in([:cells, cell1[:origin]], &(Cell.link(&1, cell2)))
    |> do_bidirectional(cell1, cell2, bidirectional, &link/4)
  end
  def link(maze, {_, _} = pt1, {_, _} = pt2, bidirectional) do
    link(maze, maze[:cells][pt1], maze[:cells][pt2], bidirectional)
  end

  def unlink(maze, %{} = cell1, %{} = cell2, bidirectional \\ true) do
    maze
    |> update_in([:cells, cell1[:origin]], &(Cell.unlink(&1, cell2)))
    |> do_bidirectional(cell1, cell2, bidirectional, &unlink/4)
  end

  defp do_bidirectional(maze, _, _, false, _), do: maze
  defp do_bidirectional(maze, cell1, cell2, _, fun) do
    fun.(maze, cell2, cell1, false)
  end
end

defmodule Cell do
  def create(row,column), do: %{origin: {row, column}, links: %{}}
  def link(self, cell) do
    update_in(self, [:links, cell[:origin]], fn _ -> true end)
  end
  def unlink(self, cell) do
    update_in(self, [:links], &Map.delete(&1, cell[:origin]))
  end
end

iex(26)> Maze.new() |>
...(26)> Maze.new_cell(0,1) |>
...(26)> Maze.new_cell(1,0) |>
...(26)> Maze.link({0,0}, {0,1}) |>
...(26)> Maze.link({0,0}, {1,0})
%{cells: %{{0,
     0} => %{links: %{{0, 1} => true, {1, 0} => true}, origin: {0, 0}},
    {0, 1} => %{links: %{{0, 0} => true}, origin: {0, 1}},
    {1, 0} => %{links: %{{0, 0} => true}, origin: {1, 0}}},
  tree: {{0, 0}, nil, nil}}
iex(27)>
```